# How to reset Windows battery usage history statistics?

Tags: windows-10, battery, powercfg

When I run a `powercfg /batteryreport` on Windows 10, I get a nice looking HTML report that includes battery usage history going back ~ 19 months. I suppose this is stored somewhere in my computer's operating system (or is it in the battery controller?).

How do I clear it and start fresh? I have replaced the laptop's battery and I want new statistics. I've read that I can charge and discharge to get Windows to get new information for its estimates, but my question here is about the full history data: **where is it stored, and how can I reset it?**

Comment: The data is read from the battery.  If you want the last 30 days, Powercfg /batteryreport /duration 30, is a better solution than replacing the battery

Comment: Depending on your particular computer, you can reset the battery and that should clear out statistics. You need to look at your computer documentation as different computers have different features.

Comment: I am surprised that the battery itself (the hardware controller?) might be keeping historic information going back months. It would make much more sense to me that it is the software controller or the OS storing that. Do you have any reference where I can read more about this?
Anyway, just to clarify, my battery replacement was needed because the old battery was becoming useless. That's the reason why I want to understand how this historic data is saved, to make sure it adapts to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to reset Windows. Battery report showed more than 2 years of usage history before resetting. After the reset, powercfg /batteryreport was successfully cleared and the html report showed only 1 entry.